# Query string keep on appending sharepoint 2013 navigation

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to add query string in navigation like bellow,

```
/sites/A/B/Home.aspx?location=Home&subLocation=B
```

but it is keep on appending query string like

```
/sites/A/B/Home.aspx?location=Home&subLocation=B?
?location=Home&subLocation=B
?location=Home&subLocation=B
?location=Home&subLocation=B
?location=Home&subLocation=B
?location=Home&subLocation=B
```

I've tried http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/4fc5ccca-e49e-421d-b2e0-c7a50ae47550/

still not solved ..................

Please help.............

Answer (score 0):

If you add "&" to the end of the string, the appending will not effect the outcome. In this post seems like updating SP CU will solve the issue. Ive not tried it though.  You can check [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/3d6fc166-f50a-4663-b89d-cf4d9588dc97/query-string-keep-on-uppending-in-navigation?forum=sharepointgeneral).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post.

Comment: I updated to SharePoint 2013 SP1 ...and issue is resolved.... Microsoft has resolved this issue might in June CU or some other CU's not sure....